# Hide the first div with specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to hide (display:none) the first div with class .leftAddress

Here is css

```
fieldset .leftAddress:first-of-type{
    display:none;
}
```

Here is html

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="alert forward"><span class="coming"><strong>NOTE:</strong></span> A maximum of 5 address book entries allowed.</div>
    <div class="leftAddress">Any</div>
    <div class="leftAddress"> 
        <!--Insert-->
        <h3 class="addressBookDefaultName">Harry Testing</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="leftAddress"> 
        <!--Insert-->
        <h3 class="addressBookDefaultName">Heba ElZany</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="leftAddress"> 
        <!--Insert-->
        <h3 class="addressBookDefaultName">Yamen Shahin&nbsp;(primary address)</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="leftAddress"> 
        <!--Insert-->
        <h3 class="addressBookDefaultName">Yamen2 Shahin2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="leftAddress"> 
        <!--Insert-->
        <h3 class="addressBookDefaultName">Yamen3 Shahin3</h3>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

As you see I used `:first-of-type`, but it seems to be not working. What am I missing here?
I also tried :nth-of-type(1) http://jsfiddle.net/arns7/4/ it doesn't work.
So this solution didn't work for me [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: `first-of-type` is applicable for elements and not classes. CSS doesn't have a `first-of-class` kind of selector.

Comment: Is the use of jQuery/javascript an option in this instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **CSS Based Solution:**

With CSS, there is no direct way to do this as far as I am aware. However, you can do the below as a work-around solution.

```
fieldset .leftAddress {
    display:none;
}
fieldset .leftAddress ~ .leftAddress {
    display: block;
}
```

**Explanation:** The first rule sets the `display` as `none` for all elements with `.leftAddress` class under the fieldset and then the second one sets `display` to `block` for all elements with `.leftAddress` class which also has a preceeding sibling with the same class. Thus in total, the first element with class as `.leftAddress` remains hidden.

[**CSS Solution Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QzELk/)

**Note:** As pointed out by [xec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833146/xec) in comments, the CSS solution works only when used on elements which are siblings. If they are not and say there is one element with `class='leftAddress'` inside a wrapper (another level) within the fieldset, both the first `.leftAddress` in the fieldset and the first `.leftAddress` within the wrapper in the fieldset will get hidden (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QzELk/2/)).

So, in essence **it hides the first element with that class within the same parent**.

---

### **Javascript Based Solution:**

If you don't have any problems with using Javascript to achieve this effect, you can do it using the below code. This solution doesn't have the limitation mentioned in the CSS based solution (sample can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QzELk/3/)).

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('leftAddress')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

1. `document.getElementsByClassName('leftAddress')[0]` - Gets the first element in the DOM with class name as `leftAddress`. The `[0]` is mandatory because `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes (as the plural name suggests) and hence we have to reference it like we do with any array.
2. `style.display = 'none'` - Javascript equivalent of the CSS `display: none`.

[**JS Solution Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QzELk/1/)

**Note:** As mentioned in Point 1, this currently hides the first element with that class within the entire document. If you want to restrict it to the first element with that class within the `fieldset`, that can also be done.

Comment: +1 Maybe also worth noting that this will work for siblings only, as opposed to the first found instance of `.leftAddress` on the page as a whole (like jquery's `$(".leftAddress").first()` would do)

Comment: @xec: Spot on mate. That is one thing that I overlooked probably because the user had `fieldset .leftAddress...` in his original selector.

Comment: Another sidenote: `document.querySelector(".leftAddress")` would also work :) (IE8+)

Comment: @xec: True, but the general sibling selector I believe works in older versions of IE also.

Comment: @Harry Your solution work for me. You helped me a lot. Thanks
I used the css only solution.