# first and last class selector in pure CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select only the first and the last classes over the entire document using only pure CSS,
in my case the structure is the following:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div>
        <div class="Parent"></div>
        <pre>
            <span>
                <span class="myClass">YES</span>
                <span class="myClass">NO</span>
                <span class="myClass">NO</span>
            </span>
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="Parent"></div>
        <pre>
            <span>
                <span class="myClass">NO</span>
                <span class="myClass">NO</span>
                <span class="myClass">YES</span>
            </span>
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/69uHu/)

**NOTE:**
I'm trying to apply this on a real codemirror matchtags, I'm not sure if that the structure that I posted is correct..
[Here the real codemirror matchtags demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/matchtags.html)

Comment: CSS cannot select by class like that.

Comment: With pure CSS that is not possible. I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094913/hide-the-first-div-with-specific-class/25094973#25094973) yesterday on a similar item (for first class) and there is an even bigger answer posted by BoltClock linked in that thread. Please check if they are of help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: @Paulie_D: It's hard to tell if the questions are the same, as the first and last child with a class, and the first and last in the whole document, aren't necessarily the same thing. I just updated my answer over there to note the difference.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is what you need:

```
.CodeMirror-code > div:first-child  .cm-tag:first-child {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.CodeMirror-code > div:last-child .cm-tag:last-child {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/69uHu/2/)**

**Note**: This solution relies on the assumption that all the span elements contain a common class cm-tag - as the OP's fiddle shows.

Comment: @danield yes but in the real page this seems not work... [please have a look](http://codemirror.net/demo/matchtags.html)

Comment: @Harry - yes, I just noted that in my answer. But from the OP's code it does look like this is the case

Comment: @Danield: Agreed mate. On first look it does seem that way.